# Gitlab renders index.md files different than local hugo does

Tags: hugo

I’m building a personal hugo website and am deploying it via Gitlab pages. This worked pretty well so far, except for a strange bug I ran into recently:
I’ve changed my homepage from “_index.md” to “index.md” (topmost index file in the tree) in order to access pictures in sub-folders as page resources, which I wasn’t able to access with it named “_index.md”. This worked well building the page locally (using hugo 0.88.1), but as soon as I’ve uploaded these changes to Gitlab, my gitlab page became nearly empty (no content (where pictures were included), just header and footer).

I’ve played a while with gitlab-ci in order to track it down.
Resulting page as expected: Files · bd036ee1b5eee9481cda3673414dcaff8a2753da · Roy Meissner / rmeissn.gitlab.io · GitLab 2
Resulting page nearly empty: Files · e885460a88ae9b7e6f1356fcdcb90ac4a33c5351 · Roy Meissner / rmeissn.gitlab.io · GitLab 2
The second link is just one commit later, renaming “_index.md” to “index.md”. This won’t raise any CLI warning/error locally or on gitlab-ci.

Content of the nearly empty index.html from the gitlab build artifact:

```
<!doctype html><html lang=de-de><head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name=description content="Hompage of Roy Meissner">
<meta name=author content="Roy Meissner">
<title>Webseite über Roy Meissner</title>
<meta name=generator content="Hugo 0.88.1">
<noscript>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/fontawesome.min.css defer>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/solid.min.css defer>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/brands.min.css defer>
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" defer>
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" defer>
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic" defer>
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700" defer>
</noscript>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://rmeissn.gitlab.io/css/vendor.min.ff6fc787c4ec5df9d28a94e2875fb22fbec3b8e1f62707323f7251d74ecfb34ff23e2b16eefbbd7847059cae69e514aaf398b178885f906e688ecbbb5b6a0e36.css integrity="sha512-/2/Hh8TsXfnSipTih1+yL77DuOH2JwcyP3JR107Ps0/yPisW7vu9eEcFnK5p5RSq85ixeIhfkG5ojsu7W2oONg==" media=screen>
<link rel=icon href=https://rmeissn.gitlab.io/favicon.png type=image/png>
</head>
<body id=page-top class=index>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id=mainNav>
<div class=container>
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href=https://rmeissn.gitlab.io/>Roy Meissner</a>
<button class=navbar-toggler type=button data-bs-toggle=collapse data-bs-target=#navbarResponsive aria-controls=navbarResponsive aria-expanded=false aria-label="Toggle navigation">
Menu <i class="fas fa-bars ms-1"></i>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id=navbarResponsive>
<ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
<li class=nav-item>
<a class=nav-link href=#services>3 Säulen</a>
</li>
<li class=nav-item>
<a class=nav-link href=#portfolio>Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li class=nav-item>
<a class=nav-link href=#about>Über mich</a>
</li>
<li class=nav-item>
<a class=nav-link href=#clients>Institutionen</a>
</li>
<li class=nav-item>
<a class=nav-link href=#contact>Kontakt</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<div></div>
<footer class="footer py-4">
<div class=container>
<div class="row align-items-center">
<div class=col-lg-6>
<div class=social-buttons>
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2 hoverTransition" href=mailto:roy-meissner@gmx.net target=_blank rel=noreferrer alt=E-Mail>
<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2 hoverTransition" href=https://www.xing.com/profile/Roy_Meissner2 target=_blank rel=noreferrer alt=Xing>
<i class="fab fa-xing"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2 hoverTransition" href=https://github.com/rmeissn target=_blank rel=noreferrer alt=Github>
<i class="fab fa-github"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2 hoverTransition" href=https://gitlab.com/rmeissn target=_blank rel=noreferrer alt=Gitlab>
<i class="fab fa-gitlab"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2 hoverTransition" href=https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404508/roy target=_blank rel=noreferrer alt=Stackoverflow>
<i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2 hoverTransition" href=https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4193-8209 target=_blank rel=noreferrer alt=ORCiD>
<i class="fab fa-orcid"></i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 text-lg-middle">
<a class="page-scroll hoverTransition" href=#page-top><i class="fa fa-arrow-up">&nbsp;Seitenanfang</i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
<script type=text/javascript defer>let link,godefer;link=document.createElement('link'),link.rel='stylesheet',link.href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/fontawesome.min.css',link.type='text/css',godefer=document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0],godefer.appendChild(link),link=document.createElement('link'),link.rel='stylesheet',link.href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/solid.min.css',link.type='text/css',godefer=document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0],godefer.appendChild(link),link=document.createElement('link'),link.rel='stylesheet',link.href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/brands.min.css',link.type='text/css',godefer=document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0],godefer.appendChild(link),link=document.createElement('link'),link.rel='stylesheet',link.href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700',link.type='text/css',godefer=document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0],godefer.appendChild(link),link=document.createElement('link'),link.rel='stylesheet',link.href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan\u002bScript',link.type='text/css',godefer=document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0],godefer.appendChild(link),link=document.createElement('link'),link.rel='stylesheet',link.href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid\u002bSerif:400,700,400italic,700italic',link.type='text/css',godefer=document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0],godefer.appendChild(link),link=document.createElement('link'),link.rel='stylesheet',link.href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto\u002bSlab:400,100,300,700',link.type='text/css',godefer=document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0],godefer.appendChild(link)</script>
<script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js></script>
<script src=https://rmeissn.gitlab.io/js/vendor.min.77bdf77320261d22ed734ff16f0e4368ddb1346535a15c8dcd76bae46e9e43d496530bf68e645dca6f8c68770fc60860409751afc32af88a01d6370dfed0658b.js integrity="sha512-d733cyAmHSLtc0/xbw5DaN2xNGU1oVyNzXa65G6eQ9SWUwv2jmRdym+MaHcPxghgQJdRr8Mq+IoB1jcN/tBliw=="></script>
<script src=https://rmeissn.gitlab.io/js/deferred.min.cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e.js integrity="sha512-z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ1m2AB9Yg5AULVxXcg/SpIdNs6c5H0NE8XYXysP+DGNKHfuwvY7kxvUdBeoGlODJ6+SfaPg==" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why is gitlab producing different results than hugo locally? I even tried downloading the docker image and executing the gitlab-ci commands within it… which gives me the expected results (a page full of content) for both commits.

Comment: Can you post the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file please?

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical one and this happens quite often in the beginning, especially when you don't fully understand the concept of page bundles (who does?). The problem is that Hugo does not clean up after itsself. The index on localhost 'no longer exists', but you are still able to visit it. When you restart Hugo you will see the true version of your website and get a 404 on that index (on localhost). Another reason can be that it is using another template file. Restarting Hugo helps in those cases. To debug the situation you should manually run the 'hugo' command and look in the 'public' directory (remove the directory after analysis, as it is not cleaned either).

Comment: thanks Mr.Hugo, I read earlier about the 'emptying Public folder' .. yes, Hugo does not clean its cache (?), and once i simply deleted the Public folder from my project source (~/quickstart), pushed to git, waited a minute, refreshed the tab's showing my webpages... all work updated!